# choose MAX sub-category if null

Tags: snowflake

Here is some made-up data as an example:

| Category | Sub-Category | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Furniture | Chairs | 25 |
| Furniture | Null | 15 |
| Technology | Null | 10 |
| Technology | Phones | 35 |

What I'm trying to do is... Keeping CATEGORY fixed, choose the non-null subcategory.

so this would be what would happen:

| Category | Sub-Category | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Furniture | Chairs | 25 |
| Furniture | Chairs | 15 |
| Technology | Phones | 10 |
| Technology | Phones | 35 |

and this would be the output:

| Category | Sub-Category | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Furniture | Chairs | 40 |
| Technology | Phones | 45 |

I figured out how to do this within Tableau, but I need to figure out how to do this in SQL.

Here is the solution inside Tableau:

```
IFNULL ([Sub-Category],
{FIXED [Category] : MAX([Sub-Category]) } )
```

Btw:  there is much more to why I'm doing this, and right now it looks like "why would she want to do this?", but there is a reason that makes sense, but can't explain because I'm not allowed to show data from my job because it is confidential. The output would be a result of combining the like terms together.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please add the data that you are `actually using`? It's great that you've resolved your issue, but this whole thread will be completely useless unless you include the relevant tables (DML) and maybe a bit more data also (DDL)? I'm regretully voting to close (VtC - don't like doing this to New Contributors) until the further information I've requested is forthcoming - TIA! @Lennart FYI.

Comment: hmmm... Do people actually post the real data that they are actually using at work?  Sounds like a great way to get fired.

Answer (score 1):

With the data that I'm actually using (vs. the data in the example), I had to add in an additional field for the partition (not shown here), but it would look something like this...

```sql
CASE
  WHEN SUBCATEGORY IS NULL THEN
    FIRST_VALUE(SUBCATEGORY)
    OVER (PARTITION BY ADDITIONAL_FIELD,CATEGORY
          ORDER BY SUBCATEGORY NULLS LAST)
  ELSE
    SUBCATEGORY
END AS NEW_SUBCATEGORY
```

Full query:

```sql
SELECT
  ORDERID,
  CATEGORY,
  NEW_SUBCATEGORY,
  SUM(COUNTS) AS NEW_COUNTS
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ORDERID,
      CATEGORY,
      SUBCATEGORY,
      CASE WHEN SUBCATEGORY IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(SUBCATEGORY) OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY SUBCATEGORY NULLS LAST) ELSE SUBCATEGORY END AS NEW_SUBCATEGORY,
      COUNT(*) AS COUNTS
    FROM ORDER_TABLE
    GROUP BY
      ORDERID,
      CATEGORY,
      SUBCATEGORY
  )T
GROUP BY
  ORDERID,
  CATEGORY,
  NEW_SUBCATEGORY;
```

Comment: While it's great that you've solved your issue - because of missing fields we don't know what issue. This renders the question not very helpful and possibly even misleading for those following a search! Could you please edit your question with this (important, relevant data) - then it will make sense and also be helpful to others down the line. I appreciate that you are a "new kid on the block", but the aim here is ultimately to help others... p.s. you didn't answer my question `what if there's more than 1 sub_category per category?` - could you please expand on both issues?